# How to derive the relationship between gamma and theta?

Tags: options, finance-mathematics, greeks

I am trying to derive this formula Θ = –0.5 × Γ × S^2 × σ^2 to see where it comes from.

My thinking is that PnL = delta dS + Vdσ + 0.5Γ(dS)^2 + Θdt.
Assume we delta hedged and vega hedged, first and second term drops off, so we have PnL = 0.5Γ(dS)^2 + Θdt.

Now assuming no free lunch, PnL = 0. Hence, 0 = 0.5Γ(dS)^2 + Θdt.

Here I am stuck

Comment: Is this relationship true for all products?

Comment: Assume no dividend (q=0), a European Call, and compare the Black Scholes formula for Θ and the formula for Γ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks Notice how similar the two formulas are...

Comment: Strictly speaking this holds when there is no carry. Also, you mentioned vega hedging which in a BS world is not necessary. In a non BS world, even if you delta and vega hedge there will be vanna and volga in addition to Gamma to balance the theta. This is all a consequence of the fact that the option price is a martingale and the corresponding PDE.

Comment: A bit off topic: I think [Mercurio](https://docplayer.net/8423036-A-vega-gamma-relationship-for-european-style-or-barrier-options-in-the-black-scholes-model.html) once showed the relationship between vega and gamma in a diffusion setting; and even ISDA SIMM made use of that relationship ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing in your notation, it is the expected PnL=0, so

E[0.5$\Gamma $dS^2 +$ \theta $dT]=0

Now, E[dS^2]= $\sigma$^2 dT

So we are done, except to note that your $\Gamma$ is the dollar gamma whereas most textbooks use the gamma per unit of stock, and they are related by a factor of S^2.